# Name of primary key column is always id when using Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-5.3

Let say I have a table with table structure as following:

```
Table_A
    sid (auto increment, primary)
    .... some other column ....
    created_at (created using laravel eloquent timestamps() function)
    updated_at (same as above)
```

Then, I created a new column by.

```
$new_row = new TableA; //TableA is a model created pointing to Table_A
$new_row->col1 = 'Some value';
$new_row->col2 = 'Some other value';
// Some other field
$new_row->save()
```

Then, right after this section of code,

```
dd($new_row->sid);
```

Surprisingly, the output is:

```
null
```

However, when I change it to:

```
dd($new_row->id);
```

It returns the sid (i.e. the primary key value of the row). Is the name of the primary key always id when I am using auto-increment as my primary key in Laravel Model? Or why am I only getting the value when I use the name `id`?

---

P.S. Let me make myself clear: I know how I can get the primary key value, and I know I can set the name of primary key in model. What I want to know is if this behavior holds for all primary key, or just those with primary key.

Answer (score 5):

In you model define primary key.This will override default primary key id

```
protected $primaryKey = 'sid';
```

Comment: Even if I actually don't have the column named id?

Comment: laravel uses take default id as primary key

Comment: I am not asking for solution in this answer. I said that I know I can use $new_row->id to get what I want. I am asking for why is it always id even if I don't have the column named "id" at all. If I am not using something not auto-increment as primary key, is it still id?